# JS Confirm Ok & Cancel on gridview page indexing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview and on Page Indexing I need to show an confirm box alert with Ok and Cancel. I have an update button in the page and gridview has dropdown values. When user changes the dropdown values in gridview and try to move to next page without clicking update button, then I need to show an alert like "Make sure you have updated the changes before navigation". I have tried lot of JS and nothing helped.

I am using this peice of code in my page indexing. The alert pops up but not the confirm box with Ok and Cancel.

```
string script = "alert('Make sure you have updated the page before navigation!')";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

**My Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Application_Service_Sizing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Application_Service_Sizing" %>

<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="head" runat="Server">
<div id="paging">
        <asp:scriptmanager runat="server">
        </asp:scriptmanager>
        <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
            <contenttemplate>
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" allowpaging="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging"
    autogeneratecolumns="False" onrowdatabound="RowDataBound" pagesize="100" datakeynames="Products"
    width="1000px" cssclass="manlog">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
     <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tran_date" HeaderText="Transaction Date"
                SortExpression="tran_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RSQ" HeaderText="Transaction Cash"
                SortExpression="RSQ" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RSU" HeaderText="Cash Unit"
                SortExpression="RSU" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CSQ" HeaderText="Credit sale"
                SortExpression="CSQ" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CSU" HeaderText="Credit Unit"
                SortExpression="CSU" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="iAmount" HeaderText="Amount"
                SortExpression="iAmount" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>
    </div>  
</asp:content>
```

**Page Indexing:**

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to retain the drop down selected value among page index changes?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user changes the dropdownlist then at that time set a property in a Hidden field. and call the confirm box when HiddenField is set.

```
 $("#divID").click(function() {
 if(check value of hidden field){
        if (!confirm('Make sure you have updated the changes before navigation')) 
             { return false; }
     }
    }
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4ZyX/)

**EDIT**
Check Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9dCe/)**

Comment: Yeah the alert comes fine. But the confirm box doesn't come like OK & Cancel. If they click OK it will take to next page and if they click Cancel they have to stay in the same page.

Comment: I have posted my try as an answer. Problem is when I click cancel in the confirm box, the confirm repeats 3 times. Also when I click OK its not moving to next page. Believe I will have to give my aspx page in href. Pls correct me if I am wrong.